# Error on npm install [new package]

Tags: node.js, npm

When installing a new package to my node_modules, I get the following error:

```
npm install --save [package]

npm ERR! path /home/user/Dev/application-name-example/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/node_modules/delegates
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/user/Dev/application-name-example/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/node_modules/delegates' -> '/home/user/Dev/application-name-example/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/node_modules/.delegates.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2017-08-28T11_02_39_419Z-debug.log
```

The specific file it cant rename varies within a few common offenders, but it's always a rename issue. I can fix this with `rm -rf node_modules`, but it's not an ideal solution to have to do that each time.

Similar questions I've seen suggest doing just that: 
[npm: ENOENT: no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33640805/1399115)

This is only happening on a new project, and isn't happening on old ones, does anyone know why? Is it related to path-length or package.json configuration?

Comment: Do you have already package.json in your directory?

Comment: Yes. It's there.

Comment: Ok, I had the same error trying to install a module in a project without package.json ... then I created the file, using npm init, and I resolved! Perhaps you are right, the problem is into package.json if you set some custom configurations! I suggest to you to share part of this file so the experts will help you better than me.